# Call variable from another function with struct

Tags: c, struct

I am new to C and I've just learnt about `struct`. I am to make a program that reads data from a file and prints it.

One of my sub-tasks is to calculate the distance between 2 points. I am using the haversine formula as seen by the distance function.

My issue however is that I am trying to get `fst->Lat` and `fst->Long` from the `stage_1_read` function and it's not working.I have highlighted the lines they are in, to make it clear.

How do I get these values? They are the 2nd and 3rd values read in the file, but with my current code, it looks like it is reading the 1st and 2nd values instead. I have been trying for a while now but just cant get the values I need.

```
struct file_data{
    char User[5];
    char Long[12];
    char Lat[12];
    char Date[11];
    char Time[3];
};

double stage_1_read(void);
double distance(struct file_data fst);
double toRadian(double x);

int main(){
    printf("%f", stage_1_read());
    return 0;
}

double stage_1_read(void){
    /* This function takes the data from the input file,reading and printing 
    the User ID, Location (longitude and latitude), Date, Time, and Distance*/
    double d;
    char line[256];
    struct file_data fst;

    if (fgets(line, 256, stdin) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s", fst.User, fst.Long, fst.Lat,
        fst.Date, fst.Time);
    }
    else{
        printf("Failed to read file. Check file and try again.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    d = distance(fst);
    printf("Stage 1\n==========\n");
    printf("User: #%s\n", fst.User);
    printf("Location: <%s %s>\n", fst.Long, fst.Lat);
    printf("Date: %s\n", fst.Date);
    printf("Time: %s\n", fst.Time);
    printf("Distance to reference: %.2f", d);
    return 0;
}

double distance(struct file_data fst) {
    /* This function is designed to calculate the distance between the check-in 
    POI and the reference point provided*/
    double angle_distance, chord_length, dist;
    double lat_2, long_2;

    lat_2 = *fst.Lat;
    long_2 = *fst.Long;

    double var_lat = toRadian(lat_2 - LAT_1);
    double var_long = toRadian(long_2 - LONG_1);

    chord_length = pow(sin(var_lat/2),2) + cos(toRadian(LAT_1)) * 
    cos(toRadian(lat_2)) * pow(sin(var_long/2),2);

    angle_distance = 2 * atan2(sqrt(chord_length), sqrt(1 - chord_length));

    dist = 6371 * angle_distance;

    return dist;
}

double toRadian(double x) {
    x = PI/DEGREES;
    return x;
}
```

UPDATE:

Changed some code around as requested.

Comment: 1. Turn on compiler warnings and fix them, as the first step (use `-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang* for example). 2. Check return value of `scanf` functions always.

Comment: For gcc/clang also add `-pedantic -Wshadow`. (for VS, `cl.exe` use `/W3`) Read and understand the warnings and then go fix them. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning. You can learn as much, if not more, C just by listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from any book.

Comment: Sorry, I partially misinterpreted your code. `stage_1_read()` should not take arguments, i.e. `double stage_1_read(void)`, you then need `double d;` back as a variable and assign it to the result of `distance()`, i.e. do `d = distance(&fst);` before the `printf``'s and just print `d` in the final `printf`. If you need `stage_1_read()` to return the distance, return `d`. Otherwise, make the return type `void`, remove the `return` statement and just call `stage_1_read()` in `main()`.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a little more sense. Thanks for that. One last question, when I have executed it, the distance is coming up as `Distance to reference: 157.240.000000`. This is obviously a wrong number with way too many digits, what have I missed? Code is updated in the original post

Comment: Please don't obfuscate your posts after they have been answered. I've rolled back to the last good revision.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference a variable that is declared in a different function (though I'm uncertain how declaring a pointer to the struct `struct file_data *fst` without allocating memory is working for you), you can however declare it as a local variable without the `*` and then you can refer it as `fst.Lat` instead.
If you insist on using it as a pointer, a memory should be allocated for that matter, you can use `malloc` or any other memory allocation method that suits you.

But to our business, when you reference `fst` variable from the `distance` function, you're referencing the newly variable `fst` you just declared in that function.

if you want to reference the same variable from both functions (or any function), one option is making this variable global (declare it outside of the function scope), or you can make `distance` accept a pointer to that struct as an argument

```
double distance(double d, struct file_data *fst)
```

then you will be able to access the one you created under `stage_1` function

Comment: One of the requirements of the task is to avoid using global variables, so that's why I haven't done that. In saying that, I tried changing my function to include the struct, but I'm still getting errors saying `error: declaration of 'struct file_data' will not be visible outside of this function`. How would I go about cleaning this up?

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code so I could take a look, Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it up! Also having an issue with calling the function distance(d) towards the bottom of stage_1_read when printing the values. I think it is because the parameters were changed of the distance formula, but im not too sure

Comment: Well, now `distance` accept two arguments and you pass only the first one, what about the second one?

Comment: Okay I will look to pass the other one too. What about the error im still getting? It says `warning: 'struct file_data' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration`

Comment: Not sure about the error you're getting (where does it say the issue is?). but pay attention to your variables names, you declared `struct file_data *fst` as a local variable in `distance` although it has the same name for one of its arguments.